# Strategy not being used, why?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I'm new at express and I'm trying to implement some authentication methods with passport. It seems the best option for me, i started reading several tutorials and now i have this unusual code.
Apparently the strategy *registerStrategy* is not being used because *console.log("log");* is not being showed in the server's console.
No error is thrown by node.

```js
//localStrategy.js

var registerStrategy = new localStrategy(
  function(req, res, done){
    console.log("log");
    var user = {
      username: req.user.username,
      password: req.user.password,
      name: req.body.user.name,
      lastname: req.body.user.lastname,
      email: req.body.user.email,
      event_time: req.body.user.event_time
    };
    var usernameExists = true, emailExists = true;
    var tasks = [
      function(cb){
        db.usernameExists(user.username, function(err, exists){
          if(err) return cb(err);
          usernameExists = exists;
          cb();
        });
      },
      function(cb){
        db.emailExists(user.email, function(err, exists){
          if(err) return cb(err);
          emailExists = exists;
          cb();
        });
      }
    ];
    async.parallel(tasks, function(err){
      if(err) return done(err);
      if(usernameExists || emailExists){
        return done(null, usernameExists, emailExists);
      }
      done(null, null, null);
    });

  }
);
 
 app.use(session(sessionData));
 passport.use("local-register", registerStrategy);

//routes.js

app.post("/api/register", function(req, res){
  passport.authenticate("local-register")(req, res, 
                                          function(err, usernameExists, emailExists){
    if(err) throw err;
    if(usernameExists){
      return res.status(401).json({ err: "User exists"});
    }
    else if(emailExists){
      return res.status(401).json({ err: "Email exists"});
    }
    res.status(200).json({status: "Succesful"});
  }
  );
});
```

**Where is my mistake?**

Comment: Have you checked the console error ? Is it saying localStrategy undefined ? Have you imported required files.

Comment: Yes, i've checked and there are no errors. I imported all the files or libraries required. Are you familiar with the way i called the strategy? with **("local-register")(...)** ? Thought that could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

`passport.authenticate(...)` is a function that return a `middleware` function, so the third parameter is a reference to the next `middleware` function. In your code the anonymous function:

```
function(err, usernameExists, emailExists){
    if(err) throw err;
    if(usernameExists){
      return res.status(401).json({ err: "User exists"});
    }
    else if(emailExists){
      return res.status(401).json({ err: "Email exists"});
    }
    res.status(200).json({status: "Succesful"});
})
```

should be inside the `passport.authenticate` function as a `callback`. Something like this:

```
app.post("/api/register", function(req, res){
  passport.authenticate("local-register", function(err, usernameExists, emailExists){
    if(err) throw err;
    if(usernameExists){
      return res.status(401).json({ err: "User exists"});
    }
    else if(emailExists){
      return res.status(401).json({ err: "Email exists"});
    }
    res.status(200).json({status: "Succesful"});
  })(req, res);
});
```

Also notice that the second parameter of the anonymous function should be an object supplied by the application after it has been given an opportunity to verify credentials (the user object) and the third argument is additional info about the user. With respect to the code in the LocalStrategy, in order to pass the `req` object in the parameters you need to specify the option `{passReqToCallback : true}`, after that you will have four parameters in function `callback` which are: `req`, `username`, `password` and another `callback` function, typically named `done`, so the signature should be something like this:

```
var registerStrategy = new localStrategy(
    {passReqToCallback : true},
    function(req, username, password, done){
        ...
    }
```